# How to use "by age group"

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I want to use "by age group". Do I use it correctly?

> The first graph shows why students **by age group** studied.

[image]

Comment: Your sentence is grammatically correct but difficult to understand. A better way of saying it would be "The first graph shows why people  of different age groups study." If you really want to use "by age group", you should say something like "The first graph shows why people study, classified by age group."

Comment: Or, "*The first graph shows **by age group** why students studied.*"